# Fixing the high-bit problem in PHP's crypt() implementation

Tags: passwords, hash, php

I'm working on a site that has to have compatibility with older versions of PHP, which suffer from [a high-bit issue in the Blowfish `crypt()` implementation](http://www.php.net/security/crypt_blowfish.php). Essentially, non-ASCII characters are not processed properly, and it may be possible for an attacker to reduce the brute-force space. There's a fix in 5.3.7, but I'll need to support earlier versions.

In order to work around the issue, I'm thinking of Base64 encoding the password prior to running it through `crypt()`. The idea is that `base64_encode()` is binary safe, and the output will never contain any characters whose most significant bit is set.

Is this a safe assumption, or should I look at an alternative method?

Comment: It'll shorten the maximal password length, but should work. If you want to avoid that, you can hash with a normal hash before feeding it to bcrypt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base64 output is limited to ASCII digits, letters (lowercase and uppercase), '+', '/', '=' and newline endings (CR and LF). All of these fit in the lower 7 bits.

Using Base64 encoding has the unfortunate side-effect of enlarging the data by about +33%. Since [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) has a size limit of 55 characters, so with Base64 encoding you are down to about 39 bytes.

Also, non-ASCII password characters open up the murky business of code pages (Unicode, UTF-8, Windows-1252...) and Base64 does not solve *that*; it just pushes the problem under the rug.

Comment: Any suggestions for better mitigations?

Comment: I suggest rejecting passwords with non-ASCII characters at registration time, and rejecting them _again_ if submitted for a logon.

Comment: Good idea. I'll make sure to do that.

Comment: Done. Final implementation loops through all chars (single-byte) and checks that they're 0x7F or lower, and rejects any string that violates this.

Comment: @Polynomial While users whose native script isn't Latin are trained to use ASCII passwords and so won't curse you much for it, this isn't good for security, nor in fine for usability. See [Of contraseñas, סיסמאות, and 密码](http://www.lightbluetouchpaper.org/2012/06/01/of-contrasenas-%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA-and-%E5%AF%86%E7%A0%81/) on Light Blue Touchpaper and the articles it cites. Conclusion: “for roughly half the planet whose native writing system isn’t the Latin alphabet passwords appear less secure and more difficult to use”.

Comment: @Gilles Provide a decent alternative and I'll be happy to upvote it.

Comment: @Polynomial If you insist: Require a recent enough version of PHP. Or don't use PHP. Or embed your $favorite_language interpreter and use its own non-broken `crypt`. You're sounding a little like someone who doesn't want to reinstall after a hack because they don't have time for that.

Comment: @Gilles Unfortunately reality gets in the way of such luxuries.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `effectivePass = Base64Encode(Sha256(Utf8Encode(password))))`. Takes care of encoding and length limit. Then put `effectivePass` into bcrypt.

I believe for php treats strings are raw bytes, so you probably need to set some char-encoding http-header to UTF-8 instead of encoding.

Comment: The downside of this is that SHA-256 requires `mcrypt` support, which a lot of servers won't have. I can use SHA-1, but that makes me a bit nervous... would I need to worry about length extension attacks?

Comment: I can't think of any practical problem with SHA-1 or even MD5 in this context. Neither length extensions nor collisions are relevant. You probably could get away with CRC-128 or something like that. The only downside is PR, with people screaming "SHA-1 is borked11!1", just like they do it now with MD5.